# Find a suitable number $a$ such that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3, i)=\mathbb Q(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Find a suitable number $a$ such that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3, i)=\mathbb Q(a)$

I'm thinking about $a=\sqrt 3 + i$, but I don't know how to prove it.
I need help

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your idea seems correct.
All you have to prove is, that $a\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt3,i)$ -which is obvious,- and that $\sqrt3,i\in\Bbb Q(a)$. For this,

**Hint:** $(\sqrt3-i)a=?$, and use $\frac12\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: How do you know that $\sqrt{3}-i\in \mathbb{Q}(a)$?

Comment: $\mathbb Q(a)$ is a field. If $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb Q(a)$ and $i\in \mathbb Q(a)$, then  $\sqrt{3}-i\in \mathbb Q(a)$.

Comment: @Kevin: $\sqrt3-i=4/a$.

Comment: Ok, I can prove that $a\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt3,i)$ How can we go further from that?

Comment: You also need $\sqrt 3$ and $i$ in $\Bbb Q(a)$. And, $\sqrt 3-i$ is there, as $4/a$ and thus $\sqrt 3$, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit advanced but I would like to propose a solution
that doesn't really require calculations:

Note that a basis for $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)$ over $F=\mathbb{Q}$is
$\{\alpha_{i}\beta_{j}\}_{1\leq i,j,\leq2}$ where $\alpha_{1}=1,\alpha_{2}=\sqrt{3},\beta_{1}=1,\beta_{2}=i$.

We have $4$
maps defined by $\varphi:K\to K$ by $1\to1$ and $\sqrt{3}\to\pm\sqrt{3},i\to\pm i$.

Verify that all $4$ $\varphi$ are automorphisms of $K$ that fix
$F$. Since this is the splittinf field of $(x^2-3)(x^2+1)$ over a perfect field we have it that $K/F$
is Galois since the degre of the extension is $4$ we have it that $Gal(K/F)=\{\varphi_{i}\}_{i=1}^{i=4}$ where the
$\varphi_{i}'s$ are the ones I defined above.

Note that the only automorphism of $K$ that fix $\sqrt{3}+i$ is
$Id_{K}$ hence it is a primitive element of the extension, since
otherwise $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+i)$ is a proper subfield of $K/F$
hence correspond to a proper subgroup of $K/F$, in contradiction.

Comment: Well, you *do* need to check that the four maps are automorphisms :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez - hmm, yes. but $2$ of them are for free! :) [see next comment please for a correction]

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez - in second thought - the degree of the extension is $4$ and the extension is Galois (see revised argument) so there are $4$ automorphisms. since any automorphism sends $i,\sqrt{3}$  to some conjugate of them and since they generate the extension we have it that all of the maps have to be automorphisms - no calculations required! :-)

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. $K=Q(\sqrt{3},i)$ has degree 4 and $Q(a)\subset K$.  The minimal polynomial for $a$ has degree 4, it is $x^4-4x^2+16$; so $Q(a)=K$.

Comment: How do you prove that the degree of the minimal polynomial is $4$ ?

Comment: @Belgi Since $F=Q[\sqrt{3}]\subseteq R$, it's impossible for $F$ to contain $i$, so $[F[i]:F]=2$. By the multiplicative rule for extensions, $[F[i]:Q]=[F[i]:F][F:Q]=4$.

Comment: @Belgi The polynomial $x^4-4x^2+16$ can't be factored over $Q$ and $a$ is a root.

Comment: @rschwieb - this only shows that the degree of the extension is $4$. You do not know that $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is not a proper subfield.

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik - how do you show it can not be written as a product of two polynomials of degree $2$ ?

Comment: @Belgi Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I am not talking about $Q[a]$. I'm talking about $Q[\sqrt{3},i]$

Comment: @rschwieb - I agree that is is clear that the field extension is of degree $4$. But it is not clear why $a$ is a primitive element of the extension, i.e. why the degree of the minimal polynimial is $4$.

Comment: @Belgi It's obvious that $Q[a]\subseteq Q[\sqrt{3},i]$. On the other hand, $i=(a-4a^{-1})/2$, so $i$ and $a-i=\sqrt{3}$ are in $Q[a]$, thus $Q[a]= Q[\sqrt{3},i]$.

Comment: @rschwieb - this is not the argument given by i. m. soloveichik. the argument was that the degree is $4$ **because** the minimal polynomial is of degree $4$, not the other way around.

Comment: @Belgi Oh, I see what you mean. I thought you were concerned about the result, not the method. Fair question then!

Comment: The degree of $Q(a)$ is 4 and contained in $K$ which has degree 4 so the extensions are equal.

Comment: @Belgi how can we prove that $Q[a]\subseteq Q[\sqrt{3},i]$ ? I didn't find obvious.

Comment: @user42912 do you remember what $a$ is ?

Comment: @Belgi yes of course, $a= \sqrt 3 +i$. Sorry I'm a really beginner in this subject